# Getting '500 | SERVER ERROR' after delpoying laravel 8 app on digitalocean

Tags: php, laravel

I am getting '500 |server error' after deploying my laravel 8 small website to digitalocean running nginx.My ngix configuration is successfully tested and .env is well set up.

[Routes are accessible as shown in this screenshot but still giving me the server error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cwn11.jpg)

I have also tried below command:
php artisan key:generate
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan clear-compiled
sudo chmod -R 777 <laravel_directory>/storage
sudo chmod -R 775 <laravel_directory>/bootstrap
composer dump-autoload
php artisan optimize

Trying the above commands and other online guides didn't solve anything. Any help will be highly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: "Server error" just means "something went wrong". You need to find an error log to find out _what_ went wrong, otherwise neither you nor anyone else has any chance of fixing it except by luck.

Comment: I have turned on APP_ENV=local and APP_DEBUG=true and managed to access the admin dashboard and access all backend routes contents but the frontend routes/pages still giving me the "Server error"

Comment: Look for error messages in the log    {root}/storage/logs/laravel.log